# PyQT5 + Pyinstaller - изменить имя программы Unknown

Tags: linux, pyqt5, pyinstaller

[image: Не могу найти, как сменить надпись Unknown (см скрин ниже)]

Не получается сменить надпись unknown на свою.

PyQT5 + Pyinstaller + Ubuntu18
Что пробовал:

1. На стороне Pyinstaller - в мануалах не нашел опций, позволяющих делать это (пробовал -n MYNAME)
2. В PyQT5:
   setWindowIconText('MYTEXT')
   setWhatsThis  и все примерно подходящие опции.
   app.setApplicationDisplayName('2222')
   app.setApplicationName('1111') - тоже не помогло
   Поиск по документации не был продуктивным.
   В интернете тоже не нашел.
   В самом PyQT Designer пробовал менять атрибуты - не помогло.